# What is the meaning of "native" in a seafaring / fishing context?

Tags: nineteenth-century-english

I stumbled upon the use of the word "native" in a way that I am unfamiliar with / which I don't understand.

In [The piscatorial atlas of the North Sea](https://wellcomecollection.org/works/up4zvcsn) the word "Native" is contrasted with the term "deep sea" on e.g. page 111 (lower right):

> Time of spawning - Natives, May, June and July; deep sea, September.

or:

> When caught - Deep sea, from 15th June to 4th August; Natives, 14th May to 4th August

I've looked in the [dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/native_1) and the [4<sup>th</sup>](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/native_1#native_sng_4) meaning is the most related:

> (of animals and plants) existing naturally in a place

but it still doesn't make sense: the animals in the deep sea (presumably) also exist naturally in place.

So what does "Natives" in this context mean?

---

**In reaction to [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/585402/447963)**:
I am trying to figure out what the origin of "native" is in the naming of the "native flat oyster".
Literature often cites this 1883 piscatorial atlas in the context of the native flat oyster, so I'm not sure if the atlas refers to the "native flat oyster" or if it's the other way around.
As both "deep sea" and "native" are used on the page about the [*ostrea edulis* (literally: edible oyster)](https://wellcomecollection.org/works/up4zvcsn/items?canvas=111) they seem to talk about the same oyster species, but at different locations. Deep sea as a location is (more or less) clear, but what location is "native"?

**In reaction to [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/585400/what-is-the-meaning-of-native-in-a-seafaring-fishing-context#comment1464218_585400)**:
Perhaps it is indeed a way of saying "close to shore". If so, is there a reference I can cite for this meaning of that word?

Comment: Native in context must mean close to shore. Native to the Shetlands must be a few miles off shore, no more.

Comment: @ao1910 Please [merge your accounts](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: In relation to Oysters, Chambers dictionary says in means ones raised in artificial beds.

Answer (score 1):

**Native** in this case probably refers to the **native oyster** (*ostrea edulis*) found around the British Isles, especially along the coasts and estuaries ([MarLIN](https://web.archive.org/web/20080315205955/http://www.marlin.ac.uk/species/Ostreaedulis.htm), via Internet Archive). That is in contrast to **deep sea oyster**, which would be found in the deep sea.